# Cannot connect to Websphere MQ using ASP.NET but works fine with console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ibm-mq, impersonation

I've been trying to connect to a Websphere MQ queue manager using ASP.NET but I'm unsuccessfull. My setup is as follows:
I have a DLL where my code for connecting etc is. 
I've made 2 projects (on my own PC), a ASP.NET web project and a simple console application. When using the console application I can connect to the queue and get/put messages by impersonating a local user (which is created both on the server and on my PC with same username and password - otherwise I get a MQ 2035 error).
But when calling the exact same code in my ASP.NET project I get an MQ 2059 error. If I avoid impersonating in my ASP.NET project like I do in the console application I get the 2035 AUTHENTICATION error, and by looking in the Event Viewer on the server I see an error "**SID: ((None)) could not be resolved" impersonation**".

So what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of MQ (both client and Qmgr) are you using?

Comment: Hi Shashi. I am using Websphere version 7.5 as the server and I have included those DLLs from the server into my project and added them into the GAC. I think ithe error must be related to impersonation. I just don't know why I successfully impersonate in the console application and using the exact same code in ASP.NET I don't.

Comment: A 2059 error is not likely to be about security. If you turn off the various security requirements (CONNAUTH And CHLAUTH) and just put a local user in the MCAUSER of the SVRCONN, can you connect? If not, solve that first, then gradually put the security back on.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working after all. It seems that it was an impersonation issue after all. The odd part is that first time I call my code when impersonating a local user on my PC which also is created as a local user on the server, I get a 2059. The second time I call the exact same code literally 2 seconds after,  I can now read messages from the queue. Really odd, but calling the read method twice did the trick.